# Wordpress inside Laravel Integration

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, integrate

I have one system (built in Laravel 4.2) and I want to integrate it with Wordpress.

Only authenticaed users can access this blog.

I think in 2 options:

1 -> In routes.php include something like

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth')), function() {
    Route::get("wordpress", function() {
         require_once public_path() . '/blog/wp-load.php';
         exit;
    });
});
```

Only auth users can see blogs routes. If someone try to access without login, It will show 404 error (this code doesn't work, only one example).

2 -> Integrate Laravel with Wordpress. When create a new user in Laravel, It will create also in Wordpress. When access blog, It will automatically log user into Wordpress.

Comment: You can also ask this question at their forum. As both laravel and Wordpress uses their own routing and folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mahmoud, thank you.

I solved this problem with the function wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, true);

After log-in in my system I call one function that use wp_set_auth_cookie and login the user into Wordpress.

Comment: This does **not** answer the question in a useful way. _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong.

Comment: I used the second option. Create a Wordpress user is easy, you can find it. (I answered my own question, so I marked it as answer).

After create the user, I did:

                        require("/pathToWpLoad/wp-load.php");
   $user_id = username_exists($email);
   $userdata = get_userdata($user_id);
   $user = set_current_user($user_id,$username);
   wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, true);

Answer (score 0):

To create a union user system, I suggest that you use `WordPress REST API & OAuth (Authentication System)` it has a WordPress plugin you can use the data for both sides, Laravel & WordPress.

To authenticate users from Laravel application to allow them to view WordPress specific directory, you should generate WordPress authentication cookies from Laravel then redirect.

I think these articles may help you to start:

[How to use WordPress as a backend for a Laravel Application](https://laravel-news.com/wordpress-api-with-laravel)

[Using the WordPress REST API / Authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/)

[WordPress REST API - OAuth 1.0a Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-oauth1/)